# 8 or 12 gb when dealing with mat

Tags: memory, hardware-failure, memory-management

I had a huge problem with my computer BSODying all the time and all the times it seemed to be a memory problem. I have 16 gb RAM (4*4) and checked each of my modules individually with memtest86 and what do you know one of them got a huge amount of errors and in each of all 11 test. That module has now been sent in and I hope to receive a replacement soon.

Nevertheless the three others passed with flying colors. Now, however, I don't know whether to use 8 gb or 12 gb until I receive a new module. I was going to use 12 but there are to blue and to black slots. Does that mean I can only use 2 4gb modules at a time (Color paired) or do they just work better if they are paired or is it just the design and has no meaning at all and I should just put all three module in ?

Any hardware master who can enlighten me?

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More RAM is always better than less, so use all 12GB currently available to you. The paired sticks will run in dual-channel mode, and the unpaired one in single-channel mode. More than likely you'll never notice the difference unless you're *really* taxing your system.

Comment: Great that's what I thought but nice to know. Say I put two first into slot 1 and 3 does it matter if I put my third module into slot 2 or 4 ? 
Maybe a stupid question I'm just curious :)

Comment: AFAIK it should make no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check your motherboard user manual to be sure.
But I think there is no problem using the 12gb even not paired.

I am not 100% sure however, check the manual, you should be able to find it online if you don't have the physical one.